# NameError: Name is not defined 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a piece of code (a tic tac toe game) and when I run it python always return with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/#####/Desktop/python stuff/tic tac toe.py", line 30, in  <module>
 if turn_2 == "cell1":
 NameError: name 'turn_2' is not defined
```

Or something of the sort. (You all know what errors look like).
This is the code creating problems:

```
   turn2 = input("Enter what cell you want to play on: ")
   if turn_2 == "cell1":
        print("Put an X on cell 1.")
        cell1 = "x"
   elif turn_2 == "cell2":
        print("Put an X on cell 2")
        cell2 = "x"
   elif turn2 == "cell3":
        print("Put an X on cell 3")
        cell3 = "x"
```

I apologize in advance if this looks like trash, it's my first time asking a question on the site. Any answers are much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Because `turn_2 != turn2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your variable naming and calling are different. You named the variable `turn2` but used it in the condition as `turn_2`. Change your condition to `if turn2 == "cell1":`. (Your second condition also needs to be changed).